# Why can an SVG file contain "cm" and is it displayed correctly in browsers but not in Visio or similar programs?

Tags: python, xml, svg, visio, catia

I have a problem.Unfortunately I am not really experienced yet and have not found a solution or explanation. Please forgive me for my perhaps trivial question.

I open an SVG file with the help of a Python library and draw something into it.
If I now look at the XML file, the height and width are a number with "cm".

This now leads to my problem. If I open the SVG file in a browser it will be displayed correctly and everything is fine. However, if I now open it in Visio or a similar program, the file cannot be viewed.
It is clearly due to the "cm" because when I deleted it by hand, this error did not come.
This is also the case if "px" is in the xml file instead of "cm".

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50.cm" viewBox="0 0 50.0cm 50.0cm" height="50.0cm">
```

How and why does this "phenomenon" arise?

Comment: Presumably a bug in Visio.

Comment: I copied your SVG from above, and Notepad++ complained when I saved it. I noticed that the SVG tag was not closed. When I did (<svg.../>), Notepad++ was happy, and I could open the file in Visio. The size of the page was, indeed 50cm x 50cm, but it shows in as 19.685in, since inches are Visio's default internal unit.

Comment: @VisioGuy thanks but i closed it too but in visio nothing happens

Comment: Does a drawing open in Visio at all when you drag the text/svg file into Visio? Your SVG file has no content, just a definition of the "page" size.

Comment: @VisioGuy yes it opens

Comment: Then that's not "nothing happens"! It's not clear to me if you still have an issue or not.